# How can RequiresSession be set to true while sending a message using ISendEndpoint when the queue is not created yet?

Tags: masstransit

Using `MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core`

- It is required to send a message on a queue (and enable sessions on this queue).
- The queue is not created yet on Azure Service Bus.
- Using `ISendEndpoint` to send the message.

Is there a way to configure this queue with `RequiresSession` flag anywhere **before creating the receive endpoint**?

The default implementation, as I can see, creates a queue with "Enable Sessions" set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MassTransit, your receive endpoints should configure the queue to require sessions, not the sender. Start your consuming services first.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for your clarification. It may be better if the `ISendEndpoint` did not automatically create a queue and may be failed to send the message. As the automatically created queue is now not a sessioned one.

Comment: Everyone has their own opinion, most ended up _wanting_ the queue created for _Send_ since 99.44% of people don't use message sessions. Consider yourself the exception.

Comment: In my case, Unfortunately I cannot guarantee that the consumer will start before the sender starts sending. As a workaround, I used `ManagementClient` to properly create the queue (as sessioned) before start sending, In the absence of having some way to configure the queue from the sender side.